# unable to get administrative_level_1 information for border areas in india

Tags: google-maps, geocode

Using the google geocode API I am unable to get administrative_level_1(state) information for location on border of India (Kashmir, Arunachal Pradesh, ...). Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[see issue 8450 in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8450)

from [that issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8450):

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_territorial_disputes
>
> In disputed areas, geocoding results have no country (and sometimes no administrative_area_level_1). Reverse geocoding for disputed areas returns no results (e.g. 34.0836581,74.7973681). There is work underway to make reverse geocoding work in disputed areas.