# Google maps doesn't know Girne is in Cyprus

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I work on a web application that allows users to create events at any public location in the world. We allow them to search for events in a variety of ways, including by country. We use the maps API to identify places when they create and search for events.

Got a bug report that users in Girne -- a city on the north coast of Cyprus -- does not properly retrieve the country. For example, when I search for New York City, I use a URL like this: (identifying information stripped out)

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?client=xxxxxx&result_type=&address=New+York+City&language=en&region=US&location_type=&signature=xxxxxx

The response I get contains this JSON information:

```
"address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "New York",
           "short_name" : "New York",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "New York",
           "short_name" : "NY",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
```

However, if I enter a similar request for Girne:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?client=xxxxxx&result_type=&address=Girne&language=en&region=US&location_type=&signature=xxxxxx

the same field contains only this:

```
"address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Girne",
               "short_name" : "Girne",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            }
         ],
```

Is this a bug with the data in maps? It looks like when I just search for Girne, or any specific address in Girne, in maps.google.com, it finds a location but fails to identify the country as Cyprus there too.

Comment: Anything to do with the fact that until about a year ago, Google didn't have North Cyprus mapped? : https://www.dailysabah.com/technology/2016/02/19/google-maps-adds-turkish-republic-of-northern-cyprus

Comment: possible duplicate of [unable to get administrative_level_1 information for border areas in india](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32583459/unable-to-get-administrative-level-1-information-for-border-areas-in-india) (Northern Cyprus is a "disputed region")

Answer (score 0):

We worked this out for ourselves, but the linked issue is correct. North Cyprus is a disputed territory, and legally we aren't supposed to show country names if doing so would effectively be a political statement. We found these places recently entered in our database as event locations lacking a country:

- Afytos: near Greece
- Ari'el - part of the West Bank, near Jerusalem
- Girne; Pyla - on the isle of Cyprus
- Some place in Singapore
- Istog - Serbia
- Kerch / Kerch' - Crimea

So, I learned something interesting about global politics, and also we now have an "Other" country in our search options.